# Error: Cannot find module 'connect-livereload'

Tags: grunt-contrib-watch

I was following the steps provided as on the web http://yeoman.io/. After doing with all the steps, i am facing this error message
`$ grunt
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR

> > Error: Cannot find module 'connect-livereload'
> >     Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue`

In my package.json, i have all my dependency packages

> "connect-livereload": "~0.2.0",
>   "grunt-google-cdn": "~0.2.0",
>   "grunt-ngmin": "~0.0.2",
>   "grunt-contrib-livereload": "~0.1.2"

Answer (score 44):

I've got the same issue. Fixed it this way:

```
npm install --save-dev connect-livereload
npm install
```

May be "npm install" is enough.

Comment: Nice one. Helped me on my build as well. +1

Answer (score 0):

install

```
npm install connect-livereload --save-dev
```